# Set breakpoint within a different function using dbstop

Tags: matlab

My main.m goes

```
clear all
dbstop in a.m if a1>3
x=1;
y=2;
a(x,y)
```

The a.m goes

```
function [a1, a2] = a(x,y)
   a1=x+y
   a2=x-y
   while a1<5
      a1=a1+1
   end
end
```

But when I run main.m, I face the following error.

```
Breakpoint expression 'a1>3' resulted in an error. 
The error was Undefined function or variable 'a1'
```

Why is this the case?

I also tried main.m which looks like

```
clear all
x=1;
y=2;
a(x,y)
dbstop in a.m at 5 if a1>3
```

But it results in the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noted, you can use `dbstop` to set a breakpoint in a file given a specific condition. The trick is that the condition has to be able to be able to be evaluated at *every* in the relevant file `a.m` if you do not specify a particular line number for the breakpoint.

If you look at your function `a`, you'll see that `a1` is not defined on the first line (i.e. it's not an input argument and doesn't get defined until the next line) which results in your error.

I would recommend setting a breakpoint at a specific line. In your case, I'm assuming you want to catch it at some point within the `while` loop so maybe set the conditional breakpoint at line 5.

```
dbstop in a.m at 5 if a1>3
```

Comment: I also tried that but it doesn't work. The same error occurs.

Comment: Did you try it on the exact code you've posted above? Is there a chance that `a1` isn't defined at all in your code? Also be sure the line number (5 above) is the correct one for the code you try.

Comment: @user42459 Also be sure to clear all break points (and possibly restart MATLAB) for this change to be effective. It works fine for me with the exact code you have provided.

Comment: Oh yes. The problem was caused by "conditional breakpoint a>3" not having getting cleared before a1 has values.